# IF / ELSE statement inside .yml file

Tags: travis-ci

Is there a way to use `IF`/`ELSE` inside the `.yml` file?

I wanted to define `env` variables `if` it's **not** a pull request.

Something like this idea:

```
env:
  matrix:
    if ($TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST) {
      - BROWSER='chrome_linux'    BUILD='default'
      - BROWSER='chrome_linux'    BUILD='nocompat'
      - BROWSER='firefox_linux'    BUILD='default'
      - BROWSER='firefox_linux'   BUILD='nocompat'
   }
   else {
     - BROWSER='phantomjs'    BUILD='default'
   }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this particular case would work. `TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST` is defined on the build worker, while build matrix must be constructed before handing off the job to the worker.

I suggest writing a wrapper script that takes `TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST` and set the environment variables correctly, or do something like this in `before_install`:

```
[ "${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST}" != "false" ] && BROWSER='chrome_linux' BUILD='default' || true
```

Comment: Nice to get some feedback on this! Do the `env` variables get defined and will Travis run separately also if I have several lines like this?

Comment: `script` section in `.travis.yml` is a single string or an array of strings, which is executed in sequence for each job in a build. Global `env`s and exactly one of `matrix.env` will be defined for the job.